# Bootstrap nav pills for VueJS vue-router

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-router

In the bootstrap official docs I have seen a cool nav pills set.
This is it.

```js
<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
  <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

and this is the code I currently using for navigation.

```
<ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link to="/studentDashboard">Dashboard</router-link>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link to="/buyPapers">Buy papers</router-link>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item" >
            <router-link to="/myPapers">My papers</router-link>
          </li>

  </ul>
```

What should I change to use that pills in this code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<router-link> by defult is rendered as an achor tag `<a>`.
```

Bootstap 4 nav-pills have a `<a>` tag with class `nav-link`. as below:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So just add that class to your `<router-link>`

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <router-link class="nav-link" active-class="active" to="/studentDashboard">Dashboard</router-link>
</li>
```

To add the `active` class to the nav-pill that represents the current active  route add `active-class` prop on every `

Answer (score 2):

Use the Vue router control display of the active tabs and tab content instead of Bootstrap. Each `tab-pane` should have the `active` class since the router is being used to control the display of router-view...

```
const home = { template: '<div class="tab-pane active">Home...</div>' }
const profile = { template:'<div class="tab-pane active">Profile.. </div>' }
const more  = { template:'<div class="tab-pane active">More..</div>' }
```

Then, use a method to conditionally set the `active` class on each nav pill...

```
methods: {
      activeClass: function (...names) {
        for (let name of names) {
            if (name == this.$route.name)
                return 'active';
      }
    }    
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
         <router-link to="/home" class="nav-link" :class="activeClass('home')">Home</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
         <router-link to="/profile" class="nav-link" :class="activeClass('profile')">Profile</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
         <router-link to="/more" class="nav-link" :class="activeClass('more')">More</router-link>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
      <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/go/WVx1HswJ83

Comment: Assigning `id='app'` to the root of file worked for me as: `<body><div id="app">`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
<b-nav-item to="/home" href="#">Home</b-nav-item>
<b-nav-item to="/faq" href="#">FAQ</b-nav-item>
<b-nav-item to="/contact" href="#">Contact</b-nav-item>
```

Comment: Assigning `id='app'` to the root of file worked for me as: `<body><div id="app">`